# How to access the data I post from client-side (NodeJs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I collect some data in JS;

```
var dataset = {
    "name" : undefined,
    "pass" : undefined,
    "email" : undefined,
    "birthday" : undefined,
    "agree" : false
}

function data () {

    dataset = {
        "name" : document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value,
        "pass" : document.getElementsByName("pass")[0].value,
        "email" : document.getElementsByName("email")[0].value,
        "birthday" : document.getElementsByName("birthday")[0].value,
        "agree" : false
    }

    if(document.getElementById("signupcheck").className.search("active") > -1) dataset.agree = true;

}
```

And have a NodeJs page

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})
```

I want to post the array 'dataset' to server-side, and access in NodeJs page, but I can't. I've tried to send with Ajax like in code but I've failed:

```
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/example");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("name=weweww&urd=sss");
```

NodeJs:

```
app.post("/example", function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body)
})
```

It returns "undefined" on the terminal.
How can I access the data I post from client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `body-parser` module of node js to get the data in `req.body`

```
npm install body-parser
```

in `app.js`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

for more detail

[Express body parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html)
[Body-parser NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

Comment: One more question, It returns an empty object when I post the data like xhttp.send(dataset). Which function will solve the problem?

Comment: this is problem with your xhttp request and you can debug that to make sure the data you send is not an empty object